# filtering datagridview if DataSorce is BindingList, that implements IBindingListView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, filtering, dataview

> Problem: store non-simple class property values.

I have `BindingListView<Hotel>` and this is DataSorce of my datagridview.
I would like to notice that Hotel class looks like this.

```
public class Hotel
{
    private Address address;

    private Address legalAddress;

    private Contact contacts;

    public Hotel()
    {
        address= new Address(String.Empty);
        legalAddress= new Address(String.Empty);
        contacts= new Contact(string.Empty,string.Empty,string.Empty,string.Empty);
        geo= new Geo(string.Empty);
    }

    public Contact Contacts
    {
        get { return contacts; }
        set { contacts = value; }
    }

    public Address Address
    {
        get { return address; }
        set { address = value; }
    }


    public Address LegalAddress
    {
        get { return legalAddress; }
        set { legalAddress = value; }
    }

    public string FullName { get;  set; }

    public string AdmArea { get;  set; }
}
```

and now about `Address`

```
public class Address
{
    private string fullAddress;
    private int index;


    public Address(string str)
    {
        fullAddress = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str) ? null : str;
    }

    public string FullAddress
    {
        get { return fullAddress; }
        set
        {
           fullAddress= string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) ? null : value;
        }
    }

    public string Index {
        get { return index.ToString(); }
    }
}
```

So as you can see `Adress` and `Contacts` aren't simple Types
I populate data to datagridview using reflection.

Datagridview take data fromm this options:

```
//
// District
// 
this.District.DataPropertyName = "District";
this.District.HeaderText = "District";
this.District.Name = "District";
// 
// Address
// 
this.Address.DataPropertyName = "Address.FullAddress";
this.Address.HeaderText = "Address";
this.Address.Name = "Address";
// 
// LegalAddress
// 
this.LegalAddress.DataPropertyName = "LegalAddress.FullAddress";
this.LegalAddress.HeaderText = "LegalAddress";
this.LegalAddress.Name = "LegalAddress";
```

Now I want allow user to filter data in datagridview

So I want to do something like this:[thing that I want to reach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJXr2.png)

Main idea - in list box i store every column of datagridview and in combobox I show every unique value if cells in this column(selecter in listbox)

As you can see with simple data like `Id` there is no problem.
However, when I click on LegalAddress, for example, it couldn't find values of this column.

Moreover, I want allow user to filter data by property `Index` of Address, but i don't even know how.

> So. Could you help me to get data for non-simple types.
>   Here code how i store data to combobox:

```
private void PopulateCombobox(object column)
{
    comboBox1.DataSource = null;
    BindingSource data = dataGridView.DataSource as BindingSource;
    DataGridViewColumn col = column as DataGridViewColumn;
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList(data.Count);

    // Retrieve each value and add it to the ArrayList if it isn't
    // already present. 
    foreach (Object item in data)
    {
        Object value = null;

        ICustomTypeDescriptor ictd = item as ICustomTypeDescriptor;
        if (ictd != null)
        {
            PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = ictd.GetProperties();
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in properties)
            {
                if (String.Compare(col.DataPropertyName,
                        property.Name, true /*case insensitive*/,
                        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) == 0)
                {
                    value = property.GetValue(item);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            PropertyInfo[] properties = item.GetType().GetProperties(
                BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
            {
                if (String.Compare(col.DataPropertyName,
                        property.Name, true /*case insensitive*/,
                        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) == 0)
                {
                    value = property.GetValue(item, null /*property index*/);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // Skip empty values, but note that they are present. 
        if (value == null || value == DBNull.Value)
        {

            continue;
        }

        // Add values to the ArrayList if they are not already there.
        if (!list.Contains(value))
        {
            list.Add(value);
        }
    }
    comboBox1.DataSource = list;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Solved

```
private void PopulateCombobox(object column)
{
    comboBox1.DataSource = null;
    BindingSource data = dataGridView.DataSource as BindingSource;
    DataGridViewColumn col = column as DataGridViewColumn;
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList(data.Count);

    // Retrieve each value and add it to the ArrayList if it isn't
    // already present. 
    foreach (Object item in data)
    {
        Object value = null;

        PropertyInfo[] properties = item.GetType().GetProperties(
            BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            if (String.Compare(col.DataPropertyName,
                    property.Name, true /*case insensitive*/,
                    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) == 0)
            {
                value = property.GetValue(item, null /*property index*/);
                break;
            }
            else if(property.PropertyType==typeof(Address)|| property.PropertyType == typeof(Contact) /*||property.PropertyType==typeof(Geo)*/)
            {
                string propname = col.DataPropertyName.Substring(col.DataPropertyName.IndexOf('.') + 1);
                if (string.Compare(col.DataPropertyName, property.Name + '.' + propname, true,
                        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) == 0)
                {
                    object obj = property.GetValue(item, null);
                    Type propType = obj.GetType();
                    PropertyInfo pinf = propType.GetProperty(propname);
                    value = pinf.GetValue(obj, null) == null
                        ? string.Empty
                        : pinf.GetValue(obj, null).ToString();
                }
            }
        }

        // Skip empty values, but note that they are present. 
        if (value == null || value == DBNull.Value)
        {

            continue;
        }

        // Add values to the ArrayList if they are not already there.
        if (!list.Contains(value))
        {
            list.Add(value);
        }
    }
    comboBox1.DataSource = list;
}
```

Simply if we have '.'(dot) DataPropertyName when we are going to chek maybe right part of Name will suit us(or satisfy).